# An English translation of Simon Stevin's De Thiende

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians, translations

I enjoy reading manuscripts written by mathematicians of old, and I would love to read the famous De Thiende by Simon Steven. I've done some research online here and there, but I have not found any English translations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An old English translation is available on [Google Books](https://books.google.nl/books?id=aVdIAQAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) (or in transcribed form [here](https://adcs.home.xs4all.nl/stevin/telconst/10ths.html)). The [Dictionary of Scientific Biography entry for Stevin](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/DSB/Stevin.pdf) lists several translations in its bibliography.